# Update form creates new object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have a `Trip` model and created a form so it updates existing trips.

`models.py`:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Ref. Viagem")
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name='Destino')
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Cliente")
    out_flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight, related_name="outbound_flight" ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Ida")
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotels, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Hotel")
    in_flight = models.ForeignKey (Flight, related_name="inbound_flight", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Voo Regresso")
```

`forms.py`:

```
class UpdateTrip(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateTrip, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['trip_id'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['destination'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['client'].queryset = Clients.objects.all()


    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('trip_id', 'destination', 'client', 'out_flight', 'hotel', 'in_flight')
```

And this is the `views.py` for it:

```
def trip_upd(request, trip_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateTrip(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('trips')
    else:
        form = UpdateTrip()
    return render(request, 'backend/trip_update.html', {'form': form})
```

I am using a barebones form while testing:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, this doesn't update the objects but creates a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the instance you want to update through the `instance=…` parameter:

```
def trip_upd(request, trip_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trip = Trip.objects.get(trip_id=trip_id)
        form = UpdateTrip(request.POST, instance=trip)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('trips')
    else:
        form = UpdateTrip()
    return render(request, 'backend/trip_update.html', {'form': form})
```

or you can work with [**`get_object_or_404`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) to return a HTTP 404 error, in case the object does not exists:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def trip_upd(request, trip_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trip = get_object_or_404(Trip, trip_id=trip_id)
        form = UpdateTrip(request.POST, instance=trip)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('trips')
    else:
        form = UpdateTrip()
    return render(request, 'backend/trip_update.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that in the form, you can specify the widgets in the `Meta`, which is more declarative, than writing this in the `__init__`:

```
class UpdateTrip(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Trip
        fields = ('trip_id', 'destination', 'client', 'out_flight', 'hotel', 'in_flight')
        widgets = {
            'trip_id': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'destination': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Comment: `trip_id` is not the primary key, can I replace with `trip_id=trip_id`?

Comment: @JoãodeSousa: yes you can.